# WriteToBigQuery size limit for a PCollection in streaming mode

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have simple dataflow streaming pipeline in which I read file from GCS and uploads it into BQ.
I observed that a bit bigger files do not upload into BQ - pipeline is processing the file over and over again, in general infinitely.

I did some tests to verify when pipeline will fail (silently) or will not. And here what I have found:

- file with size less than ~ 1.4GB is processed with success
- file with size larger than ~ 1.4GB silently (no errors) fails in WriteToBigQuery step.

There is no error on dataflow level, but on worker level I found message like this:
`message: "Commit failed, will be retried at higher level but may not succeed. computation = "P2", sharding_key = "4780000000000001", status = generic::internal: Windmill failed to commit the work item. CommitStatus: TOO_LARGE"`.

This is failing all the time in one specific place - `WriteToBigQuery` class has under the hood `GroupByKey` transform - and this is the problematic place. I can see in Dataflow that input element count will be the same as number of rows in a file but output count will be nothing.

My question is: Is there any threshold (1.4GB?) in Dataflow streaming mode that GroupByKey will not handle?
I saw only limit per key - 2 MB, but it does not seem to be it.

**Edit:**

Reading from GCS was just a mental shortcut.
In general this pipeline reads PubSub message in which I have path to GCS file. In next step within DoFn step this GCS file is open through GCS connector and yields row by row to the next step.

Comment: Why you are in streaming mode ? You reading files from GCS that is a bounded source and it corresponds to a batch job not streaming.

Comment: Could you give a full traceback for the error message?

Comment: @MazlumTosun I edited my post to be more clear about the design.

Comment: @robertwb I edited my post and presented full message from a worker.